# on hover one div, assign animation class on another div

Tags: css-animations

stack!

I have an animation that is assigned to the class .slide

I have on hover on a div, when I hover over the div I want the animation class be assigned to another div. Using CSS animations.

I'd appreciate the help and thanks!

Code:
http://codepen.io/iheartkode/pen/wWMQmG?editors=0110

```
share-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #FF5722;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  &:hover {
    // assign animation class to the share-icons class
  }
  p {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  }
}

.share-icons {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  top: 15px;
  left: 4px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  background: coral;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slide {
  animation: slide 2s linear;
  @keyframes slide {
    from {
      transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    to {
      transform: translateY(100px);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edited after your clarification:
Change this in your HTML:

```
<div class="share-icons slide">
```

And this in your SCSS:

```
&:hover .slide {
    // assign animation class to the share-icons class
    animation: slide 2s linear;
    @keyframes slide {
      from {
        transform: translateY(0px);
      }
      to {
        transform: translateY(100px);
      }
    }
  }
```

And then adjust the animation as needed.

And here's a fork in action:
http://codepen.io/denmch/pen/WxrLQZ

Comment: Close. but I want the slide to be assigned to the share-icons not everything.

Comment: Edited. The .slide class gets added to the .share-icons class, and the animations to .slide when .share-container is hovered.